# How To deploy MERN Stack On Digitalocean

Tags: reactjs, digital-ocean, mern

My server runs on the following ports:

- API: localhost://5000
- Frontend: localhost://3000

My server.js file looks like this:

```js
const __dirname = path.resolve()
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')))  

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
} else {
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.send('App Is Running...')
   })
}


app.use(notFound)
app.use(errorHandler)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log(`Server Is Running In ${process.env.NODE_ENV} Mode  On Port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold)
})
```

When I deploy it, it doesn't deploy successfully.

I Bought a node.js server and following the instructions that gave me a digital ocean,

When starting the server.js file:

```
root@obstacle-sports-node:~/Obstacle-Sports# pm2 start backend/server.js
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /root/Obstacle-Sports/backend/server.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
root@obstacle-sports-node:~/Obstacle-Sports#
```

This is my NGINX configuration:

```
root /var/www/html/Obstacle-Sports;
# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name hellonode;
location / {

}
location /Obstacle-Sports/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
}
```

Trying to restart NGINX returns this:

```
root@obstacle-sports-node:~/Obstacle-Sports# systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@obstacle-sports-node:~/Obstacle-Sports#
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Can you share a log from Digital Ocean or screenshot perhaps? I don't see any problem with your code

Comment: root@obstacle-sports-node:~/Obstacle-Sports# pm2 start backend/server.js
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /root/Obstacle-Sports/backend/server.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
root@obstacle-sports-node:~/Obstacle-Sports#       This is when I am start server.js file. it seems that its working

Comment: when I type   /etc/nginx/sites-available/default                   this is how looks my nginx

Comment: see my answer, I couldn't put code here

Comment: you're not supposed to put your probable faulty code in answer. Edit your question and put the code there and read the faq section about writing good question

Comment: ok, sorry, I am new here, just a moment

Comment: Wow, it seems, nobody gonna help, because of my mistake writing question, ook :))))

Comment: check out this link from DigitalOcean 

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/can-t-start-nginx-job-for-nginx-service-failed